# Snubberless TRIAC not turning on in negative cycle

Tags: simulation, triac

I have a simple circuit with a MOC and Snubberless TRIAC.

I am using the ST Snubberless Library for my simulation.

I cannot understand why the TRIAC does not turn on in the negative half cycle, even though there is a negative gate current and negative terminal voltage.

Perhaps I am burnt out of thinking about this problem for too long, a second eye would be appreciated. The model file itself could be the problem, but again, I am not sure.
[image]

The green graph is the gate current.
The orange graph is the voltage across the load.
The cyan graph is the voltage over MT2 and MT1 (VAC and Vload).

Comment: Note that snubberless TRIACs are 3 quadrant devices designed to NOT fire in 4th quadrant. You are not describing 4th  quadrant problem but it may relate.

Comment: Yes I am aware of the 4th quadrant. That is where there is a positive I_G and negative I_T, correct me if I am wrong, and here in this simulation that case does not occur.

The library has snubberless and standard models in it, using the standard model, there are no issues. There is a strong possibility that the model file itself has an error.

I am going to sit and try to make sense of the model file

Comment: Your text:"There is a strong possibility that the model file itself has an error. I am going to sit and try to make sense of the model file" I am seeing same thing.
I have a PCB using snubberless ST:"T410-600B-TR". ST model shows the operaton seen in your graph above. PCB shows the TRIAC triggers in 3rd quadrant as expected. I have not noodled through the model to find why model does not work like PCB.

Answer (score 2):

This is a mistake on Lib file.
Open lib in a text editor like notepad.
Find your part number.
change "Standard=0" to "Standard=1"